# redirect from JSP is in type pending and status canceled

Tags: java, jsp, post, restful-url

I'm having a JSP file that is calling a `REST` post call which doing a get to a remote server.
the request is being processed but get pending in the remote machine in status canceled.
can you please assist?

here is part of the JSP:`

```
<tr>
                <td><button id="registerBtn" onclick="registerClick()">Register</button></td>
                <td><button id="loginBtn" onclick="postOnClick()">Log in</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function registerClick() {

                /* var params = "{realm: astra, subjectId: " + document.getElementById('usrInpt').value + " , authInfo: omsspass}"; */
                var first = document.getElementById('firstNameInpt').value;
                var last = document.getElementById('lastNameInpt').value;
                var user = document.getElementById('usrInpt').value;
                var password = document.getElementById('passInpt').value;
                var email = document.getElementById('emailInpt').value;

                var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

                var url = "http://localhost:8080/authJ/v0/authJ/users?realm=JOES_PIZZA&uid=" + user +"&firstname=" + first + "&lastname=" + last + "&password=" + password + "&email=" + email;

                //var params = "{realm: astra, subjectId: " + document.getElementById('usrInpt').value + " , authInfo: omsspass}";

                http.open("POST", url, true);
                //http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                        document.open();
                        document.write(http.responseText);
                    }
                };
                http.send();
            }
        </script>`
```

here is the java code

```
:`@POST
    @Path("/users")
    public Response createUser(@QueryParam("uid")String uid, @QueryParam("firstname") String firstName, @QueryParam("lastname") String lastName, @QueryParam("email")String email,
            @QueryParam("password")String password, @QueryParam("realm") String realm) {
        //readProperties();
        String tokenID = getToken();
        StringBuffer openAmUrl = new StringBuffer().append("http://").append(openAmIp).append(openAmWarName).append("/identity/create?");
        openAmUrl.append("identity_name=").append(uid);
        openAmUrl.append("&identity_attribute_names=userpassword");
        openAmUrl.append("&identity_attribute_values_userpassword=").append(password);
        openAmUrl.append("&identity_attribute_names=sn");
        openAmUrl.append("&identity_attribute_values_sn=").append(lastName);
        openAmUrl.append("&identity_attribute_names=cn");
        openAmUrl.append("&identity_attribute_values_cn=").append(firstName);
        openAmUrl.append("&identity_realm=/").append(realm);
        openAmUrl.append("&identity_type=user");
        if (email != null){
            openAmUrl.append("&identity_attribute_names=mail");
            openAmUrl.append("&identity_attribute_values_mail=").append(email);
        }
        openAmUrl.append("&admin=").append(tokenID);

        URI uri = null;
        try {
            uri = new URI(openAmUrl.toString());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
    }
`
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me see if I understand this: the *second* call (i.e. Response.seeOther(uri).build() ) is the one having the status "Cancelled"?

Comment: actually I found out that in http.onreadystatechange, the http.readyState is 4 but the http.status is 0

Comment: Does the URL you're redirecting to really work?

Comment: Yes it does - I found the problem it is due to Cross Domain - I fix it by edit the execute file of the browser that will launch without security - (--disable-web-security) hope this is help for others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem it is due to Cross Domain - I fix it by edit the execute file of the browser that will launch without security - (--disable-web-security) hope this is help for others!